# Regular expression difference between PowerShell 5 and 7

Tags: regex, powershell-5.0, powershell-7.0

I have a regular expression that returns differently on PS5 vs PS7.
Running this code:

```
$ipres      = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SecOps-Institute/Tor-IP-Addresses/master/tor-exit-nodes.lst'
$iplist     = $ipres.Content.Split([Environment]::NewLine)

$iplist_v4  = $iplist | Where-Object { $_ -match '^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$' } 
$iplist_v6  = $iplist | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$' }
```

Gives different result in:
PSVersion                      5.1.22494.1000
PSVersion                      7.2.0

It is the regular expression that make all the difference.
`PSversion5` returns "as expected". The `PSversion7` returns **nothing**.
The IPv6 list contains "everything".

The sidekick here is that I shall deploy this as an Azure Function, therefore I must get it working on `PSversion7`.

## Edit:

Thanks @DavidBrabant, you tested and hintet me that it should work. Printing the $iplist variable was my error, I should have counted

```
$iplist.count
```

Then I would have seen that it contained all in one item, but when printing them it appeared as the expected result (several items). Running it on regex was meaningless, and having only one item was the reson why response from the regular expression was so strange.

```
$iplist     = $ipres.Content.Split("`n")
```

Did the trix for PS7 and works on PS5.

That raises the question, is [Environment]::NewLine the root cause?

Comment: Can you add some examples of what data you're parsing, and the results you're getting?

Comment: Your code works for me on pwsh 7.2.0.

Comment: Also works on 5.1.

Comment: Thanks for the testing, gents... I have to tripplecheck the code and run it on several computers. But on mine it just gets wrong. On 7.2 the first regular expression filters out nothing, and all is filtered out on the second filter.

Comment: I would do a clean Windows install with PS 7.2 only to see if this works for you.

Comment: You are alle very helpful, with ideas for new directions to look. 
It was one line higher.
$iplist     = $ipres.Content.Split("`n") 
did the trick.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, the first line retrives the Tor Exit Node list from GitHub. Just copy-paste the code and run. The end result shall be two lists, one with IPv4 addresses, second with IPv6. It is a part of a solution to block Tor Exit node addresses from Microsoft365 and local servers. They generate to many security alarms...

Comment: This would fail at my current location; GitHub is blocked. That's why I wanted to see example data and results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this, so I can close this issue.
The differences between PS5 and PS7 was [Environment]::NewLine, not the behaviour of the regular expression on different PowerShell versions.

```
$iplist     = $ipres.Content.Split("`n")
```

Solved it and works on PS5 and PS7